# Best way to create a gif out of a tiled image

Tags: gimp, images, gif, image-editing, tiles

I have a very large image ( >500 Mo !) containing a series of smaller images of the same size, in mosaic, as follows:

```
[ 1  2  3 ]
[ 4  5  6 ]
[ 7  8  9 ]
```

But in my case, there are hundreds of them.

I would like to make a gif of all the images, in the right order (1 to 9 here). I thought I could use GIMP to do this, but the only task of extracting the images looks complicated, so it may not be the way to go.

**How should I do ?**

thanks

Comment: Could you convert those images to separate files? Would be way easier that way.

Comment: I don't know how to do, my source image is the way i explained - I could "un-mosaic" them with some software i guess ?

Comment: You might be able to use the record function of PS. Position, save, position, save, etc then use the recorded action on the other images. I know the GIMP doesn't have the record action functionality, though you can conceivably [code your own](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are scripts such as [this](http://registry.gimp.org/node/20868) or [this](http://gimpscripts.com/2015/03/split-layer-into-tiles/) that will chop the image and export the tiles to files.

Then open an empty image of suitable size, and do *File>Open as layers* (you can select all the files in one shot).

If necessary there is even a [transpose](http://gimpscripts.com/2015/03/transpose-tileset/) script to exchange/line columns in case the first script takes them by columns first.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). This is exactly what the tool was made for.

Or to be more specific use the [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command of ImageMagick is for making montages. The montage documentation includes many examples.

And the reverse operation of montage is documented under [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_spaced). This should cover all your needs.